# Using Promises with EventEmitters

Tags: javascript, node.js

So if I have a server in node.js, I know that I can have something like:

```
server.on('request', function() {
    console.log('received request');
});
```

but I want to do the same thing using promises. I imported Q and did:

```
Q.nfcall(server.on('request')).then(function() {
    console.log('received request');
});
```

but it says "TypeError: listener must be a function." How do you do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass a *function* to [`Q.nfcall`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfcallfunc-args), not the result of calling `.on()`. Q then will supply the callback argument to the call. Use

```
Q.nfcall(server.on, 'request').then(…)
// or rather, since it wouldn't get the context right:
Q.nbind(server.on, server)('request').then(…)
Q.ninvoke(server, 'on', 'request').then(…)
```

However, this doesn't seem to be a good idea, as the [`request` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) fires multiple times but a promise can only be resolved once (it represents a single value). You might want to look into FRP instead.